# Alternative to の

Tags: particles

I would like to translate this sentence:

*In order to compensate the deviation of the actual from the requested output current, the input voltage must be adjusted.*

I would try as follows:

実際の出力電流の指令された電流からの逸脱を補正するには、入力電圧を適応させることが必要です。

I think it is correct. However, the expression "実際の出力電流の指令された電流からの逸脱" sounds awkward as "の" is mentioned three times. From my point of view, it is somehow unclear to what the second "の" is referring to.

Does anybody no an alternative for the "実際の出力電流の指令された電流からの逸脱"?
Will it be an option if I say: "実際の出力電流に於ける、指令された電流からの逸脱"?

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt is not wrong but was difficult for me to grasp which word modifies which. Something like this would be easier to read:

> 実際の出力電流と指定した出力電流との差を補正するには、…

If you want to use における, use it to describe a "broad" scope:

> 出力電流における実際値と指定値との差を補正するには、…
>
> 出力電流における、実際値の指定値からの逸脱を補正するには、…

指定値 can be replaced with 指示値, 指令値 or 要求値 according to your preference.

In addition, you may want to use 調整する instead of 適応させる. 適応 means adapting to a new environment/configuration, but this sentence seems to be about something simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I think using the second の makes it really hard to read and it would be better to use と and make it more of a contrast between the expected and actual outputs.

> 実際の出力電流**と**指令された電流**との**逸脱を補正するには
>
> In order to compensate for the deviation between the actual and expected output current